# Getting Error: "Couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge"

Tags: vhdl

I keep on getting an error on lines 28 and 40.
The error is "couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge"
Would someone be able to help me out?
I am new to VHDL and trying to make a slow counter with an internal clock in my FPGA board.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY part3 IS
    port (Clear,CLOCK_50 : IN STD_LOGIC;
        Y : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
END part3;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF part3 IS
        component Part1 is
        PORT ( Enable,Clear,CLOCK_50: IN STD_LOGIC;
            Q : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
        end component;
        
        component display_decoder is
        port(X: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
              Y: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
        end component;
        
Signal main_count,slow_count: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
Signal enable: STD_LOGIC;


Begin
    
    a : process(CLOCK_50) is
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLOCK_50)) then --Line 28
        enable <= '1';
        
        else
        enable <= '0';
        
        end if;
    end process a;
    counter1: Part1 port map(enable,Clear,CLOCK_50,main_count);
    
    b : process (CLOCK_50,main_count) is
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLOCK_50) and main_count = "0000") then --Line 40
        enable <= '1';
        else
        enable <= '0';
        end if;
    end process b;
    counter2: Part1 port map(enable,Clear,CLOCK_50,slow_count);
    
    display_hex : display_decoder port map(slow_count,y); 
end structural;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) describes the acceptable methods to use a clock edge in 6.1 Edge-sensitive sequential logic.

Answer (score 0):

A register transfers the data from the D pin to Q only on the rising edge of the clock. In your code, you have code that requires setting enable to '1' on the clock edge, which in theory in an infinitely narrow point in time, and to '0' for all other times. In reality this is impossible. You should only action a change in signal on a clock edge and maybe a reset.

In addition, you cannot assign a signal from multiple processes. Assume enable is a wire, and each process is trying to drive a signal only that wire. What happens when they both try and drive different signals at the same time?

Comment: "_A register transfers the data from the D pin to Q only on the rising edge of the clock_". Not exactly. DFFs can also be triggered on falling edges of the clock. Moreover DDR Flip-Flops exist and provide dual-edge sampling. In FPGAs they are frequently found in I/O blocks and used to implement Double-Data Rate interfaces. So, al this depends on the target technology. What the OP encounter is probably a limitation due to their target technology that does not support DDR Flip-Flops inference from VHDL.

Comment: "_you cannot assign a signal from multiple processes_". You can, if the type of the target signal is resolved, which is the case in the OP (`std_logic`). It may not be what the OP want but this is slightly different from valid/invalid VHDL description.